# how to specify offset field in SDR

Tags: spring-data-rest

I have a list of customer names. On scrolling to end of page I load the next page. Now on this same page there is an option to create a new customer. So I create a customer and add this customer in the already present list. Now after creating a new customer, when I scroll down, the next fetched page contains some customers which are already present on my front end.

My question is regarding spring data rest. Does spring data rest offers offset field in url? For example:

```
/api/users?sort=userId,desc&size=20&page=1&offset=5
```

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#paging-and-sorting

Comment: i didn't found offset in the above shared documentation link.

Comment: You specify a page and a size. Why, exactly, would you need to specify an offset?

Comment: I have a list of customer names. On scrolling to end of page I load the next page. Now on this same page there is an option to create a new customer. So I create a customer and add this customer in the already present list. Now after creating a new customer, when I scroll down, the next fetched page contains some customers which are already present on my front end.